# Expo MapView Country color

Tags: reactjs, react-native, maps, expo

I need help regarding Expo MapView.
[image]

I want to achieve this kind of representation on MapView. I tried with polygons but, it's really hard to find all the country boundaries, and not sure if that is only way I can make this.

Comment: have you tried MapBox? I think they support boundaries out of the box

Comment: @mutable2112 I wanted to find the solution with mapview, I managed to find it. I would probably use MapBox if this solution with MapView didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find the solution, and if someone have the same requirement I will explain here. I used MapView from the react-native-maps and GeoJson feature.
Also I copied json files from here: https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json

1. After you copy the content from the json file, place it somewhere in the project (I added inside assets/georgia.json
2. Go to the component and add this code:

   `import React, { Component } from 'react'`

   `import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native'`

   `import MapView, {Geojson} from 'react-native-maps';`

   `import myPlace from '../../assets/georgia.json';`

   `export default class DataCoverage extends Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <MapView
           style={styles.mapStyle}
         >
           <Geojson
             geojson={myPlace}
             strokeColor="#0568AE"
             fillColor="#009FDB"
             strokeWidth={2}
           />
         </MapView>
       );
     }
   }`

   `const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
       flex: 1,
       backgroundColor: '#fff',
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
     },
     mapStyle: {
       width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
       height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
     },
   })`
3. Map should render with highlighted country that you wanted.
4. If you want multiple countries you just copy the "features" object and paste inside global features array inside your json file (in my case: georgija.json).
5. If you have any question feel free to ask.